# KQL Regex Extraction

Tags: regex, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to pull out a file name and it's extension when it's part of a file path, here's the regex I'm using:

```
([^\\]*\.\w+)
```

Here's an example file path I've tested using regex101:

```
c:\\users\\u10061279\\appdata\\local\\temp\\2cert_desktop.xml
```

This works fine when I'm testing using regex101 etc. but when I try and put this into a query as per the below:
[ExtractQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm7de.png)

The syntax looks messed up and when I hover over the query it says it's missing '"'
[QueryError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUi1m.png)

I'm unsure how I can get this to work, I've been playing about with it for a while and can't get the errors to clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try double escaping the backslashes

Answer (score 1):

You can use '@' prefix to a string literal (similar to .NET).

More on Kusto string literals:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string

```
print m="c:\\users\\u10061279\\appdata\\local\\temp\\2cert_desktop.xml"
| project extract(@"([^\\]*\.\w+)", 1, m)
```